# Ionic 2 filter local json file

Tags: javascript, json, ionic2

I've got a a local json file that I use for a small info app built with Ionic 2. The json data looks like the following:

```
[
 {name: 'John', type: 'admin', gender: 'male', rate: 0},
 {name: 'Peter', type: 'sales', gender: 'male', rate: 1},
 {name: 'Mary', type: 'admin', gender: 'female', rate: 1},
 {name: 'Paula', type: 'tech', gender: 'female',, rate: 0}
 ]
```

The file is located in www\assets\data\people.json. Now I can create a service to access this data like so. (services\people.ts)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class PeopleService {
  private http: any;
  public data: any;

  constructor(http: Http) {
      this.http = http;
  }

  getPeople() {
     this.http.get("assets/data/people.json")
         .subscribe(res => {
             this.data = res.json();
             console.log(this.data);
         }, error => {
             console.log(error);
         });
  }
 }
```

Now if I want to get this data and apply a filter I have the following in people.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PeopleService } from '../../services/people';
import { PersonDetailPage } from '../person-detail/person-detail';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-people',
  templateUrl: 'people.html'
})
  export class PeoplePage {
  people: any;
  modData: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public peopleService: PeopleService) {

    this.selectedItem = navParams.get('item');

    this.people = peopleService;
    this.people.getPeople();

    this.modData = this.people;
    console.log(this.modData);


  }

   resetData() {
      this.modData = this.people;
  }

filterData() {
    this.modData = this.modData.filter((item) => {
        return item.name == 'Mary';
    });

}

type = this.navParams.get('type');


itemTapped(event, item) {

    this.navCtrl.push(PersonDetailPage, {
        item: item
    });
}

 ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad PeoplePage');

}

}
```

Finally, to view the data I have the following template:

```
<ion-header>

 <ion-navbar>
  <ion-buttons start>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="resetData()"><ion-icon name="refresh"></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-buttons>
  <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="filterData()"><ion-icon name="funnel"></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-buttons>
 <ion-title>People</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

 </ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
<ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
        <h2>{{ type }}</h2>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-list *ngFor="let item of modData.data" (click)="itemTapped($event, item)">

        <ion-item>
            {{item.name}} {{item.type}}

            <ion-icon *ngIf="item.rate == 1" item-right name="star" class="custom-icon"></ion-icon><br />{{item.type}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

I've got a function to filter the data as in (note that the ngFor loops through modData.data). So how do I apply the filter for modData?

```
filterData() {
    this.modData = this.modData.filter((item) => {
        return item.name == 'Mary';
    });
```

So if the filterData function is clicked the data should only display Mary's name. But the filterData fails because of the following error

```
 caused by: this.modData.filter is not a function
```

I guess it is because the modData is an object?

So how do I get the data from the PeopleService and filter it? Of course I want this to actually end up as a search box in the header.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: `this.people = peopleService;
    this.people.getPeople();

    this.modData = this.people;` what is this intended to do?

Comment: Well, I wanted to load the data into this modData (just a holder) so that I can call the resetData function to reload the full data set after filtering and the original people data stays unmodified. This was based on something I read some time ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be setting `this.modData` to

```
 this.modData = this.people.data;
```

As in PeopleService, the loaded json data is assigned to `this.data` not the service instance directly.

Can you try your logic once again by changing the `this.modData` assignment as mentioned above ?

Comment: Thanks Abhishek, I think I tried most things like that but couldn't get the right idea. The filterData function now works. Is that the only way to get the data by always referring to this.people.data. But yayyy it works!!

Comment: @boony I would prefer modifying your `getPeople()` in this way : 

`getPeople() {
     return this.http.get("assets/data/people.json");
  }` 

If I need to do some data processing in PeopleService, then I would go like this for `getPeople()` 

`getPeople() {
     return this.http.get("assets/data/people.json").then(data => {
           // processing data
           return data;
     })
  }`

And access the data like this : `this.people.getPeople().then(data => this.mockData = data.json())`

Comment: `then()` is for promises.. `http.get` returns an observable..that wont work unless you convert it

Comment: Yeah. I got confused with ionic v1(angularjs 1.x). I will just add `toPromise()` to `http.get`. i.e `getPeople() { return this.http.get("assets/data/people.json").toPromise(); }`.

Comment: Thanks both guys. This helps my understanding a great deal. Was having a huge problem understanding promises and observables and how to call the data. The examples posted here are excellent help in this area.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the provider object in `modData` not the json value.
I would suggest you subscribe to the `getPeople()` in the component to ensure you get the data *when it is received* due to the asynchronous nature of the call.Change the method like so:

```
getPeople() {
     return this.http.get("assets/data/people.json")
         .map(res => {
             this.data = res.json();
             //console.log(this.data);
             return this.data;
         });
  }
```

In your component constructor:

```
peopleService.getPeople().subscribe(data=>{
  this.modData=data;
},error=>{
  console.log(error);
});
```